# cURL doesn't point to local server

Tags: curl, server, tomcat7

I'm trying to run a curl request to a certain content manager my business uses
and the general format is as follows:

```
curl -v -u "username@email.com:pword" -X PUT http://localhost:8080/api/content/my_command/1 -F 'json={
   "identifier":"c6646f03-588d-479f-96db-33b85bc20bad",
   "stName":"CourseSession",
   "contentHost":"www.mywebsite.com",

}; type=application/json'
```

I'm getting a 403 error wrapped in HTML.

Now, I'm running the code locally on a Tomcat server, but Curl returns Apache Coyote. How can I make this
curl point to my local server?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question well. But the http://localhost:8080 allways points to the local machine on which curl is executed. If you need to run curl against the same server, you must use domain name (http://server.example.com:8080/).

Comment: Let me put my curl output up there.

So if I wanted to run curl against the same server, I would do "contentHost":"http://server.mywebsite.com:8080", ?